# how to increment the int variable in xslt?

Tags: linux, xslt

I'm working on XSLT 1.0 version I have declared an int variable that have to increase when one (if condition) condition in true. 
So can anyone tell me how to increament that variable or any soluton to that?

e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="-1" />
```

is a variable declared. Then after that I'm checking one condition

```
<xsl:if test="$serviceP=$new">

// if condition id true the i have to increment the variable value (i.e count).
//and  again have compare that count varibale value in if condition

<xsl:if test="$count &lt; 2">
// runs when condition is true.
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer, explaining why what you want is not allowed in a functional language and how one solves such kind of problems without any variable reassignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XSLT is a functional language and as such has immutable variables -- once assigned their contents cannot be changed**.

You need to stop thinking procedurally. Explain your problem and many people will show you how to solve this problem without incrementing any variable.

**For example, the solution can be as simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    Latest Service:
     <xsl:apply-templates select="service[@new='true'][1]"/>

     New Services:
     <xsl:apply-templates select="service[@new='true'][position() >1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On more complex situations, you may write a template that calls itself recursively, passing a specific parameter with value 1-greater than the value it has in the current template call.